# Cordova ios app is not showing up in notifications center

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

I started having a problem with my Cordova app just a few days ago. The app will not show up in notifications center anymore, despite my tries to re-install the push plugin, re-new all certificates and provision profiles. The plugin I am using is the [Phonegap Push Notifications](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push). I did notice that it still has "Notifications" setting in the app preferences in iOS Simulator, although I don't think that counts as much.

Does anybody have an idea of what's going on? I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: If you do a reinstall, does it appears the notification asking for allowing notifications? Does your app register well to APN? Have you tried in a real device?

Comment: always check the notifications in devices rather than simulator.

Comment: I mentioned about the simulator in hopes that maybe it will give you an idea or something. I did reinstall the app, on a real device, many times and still the same. It just will not appear in notifications center. I am using Cordova ios 4.0.0.